# Android Security Level and Password Mechanism

Tags: android, security

I was thinking about how secure is android operating system when i asked myself the question that windows and Linux system have been hackable in the past and tried searching over google about this question.Unfortunately even after spending half a day on it i was not satisfied with what i found over the internet. I want to know how the android security and passwords mechanism work. If anybody could share anything or direct me to links that would be helpful :)

Comment: What *precisely* do you consider "the android security and passwords mechanism" to be?

Comment: the password mechanism that android os is using. Like in unix passwords are encrypted using data encryption standard.(network Security Related stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android password handling is detailed in the sources at [LockPatternUtils.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/HEAD/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java), near line 820:

```
public byte[] passwordToHash(String password) {
    if (password == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String algo = null;
    byte[] hashed = null;
    try {
        byte[] saltedPassword = (password + getSalt()).getBytes();
        byte[] sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance(algo = "SHA-1").digest(saltedPassword);
        byte[] md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance(algo = "MD5").digest(saltedPassword);
        hashed = (toHex(sha1) + toHex(md5)).getBytes();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to encode string because of missing algorithm: " + algo);
    }
    return hashed;
}
```

It looks like the general idea is to force a bad you to guess a correct password constrained by both MD5 and SHA1. That means a bad guy must get the intersection (not union) the MD5 and SHA-1 hashes.

Unfortunately, the MD5 component allows for password recovery. Perhaps a better strategy would have been folding MD5 into SHA-1 (to remove naked access to MD5).

By the way, there is a bug report for that (TM): [Lock Pattern/Password uses MD5 Hash (LockPatternUtils.java)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37213).